# What is the performance hit for the compiler if it initializes variables?

Tags: c++, c, performance, compiler-construction

Sutter says this:

> "In the low-level efficiency tradition of C and C++ alike, the
>   compiler is often not required to initialize variables unless you do
>   it explicitly (e.g., local variables, forgotten members omitted from
>   constructor initializer lists)"

I have always wondered why the compiler doesn't initialize primitives like int32 and float to 0. What is the performance hit if the compiler initializes it? It should be better than incorrect code.

Comment: Imagine if you have large arrays on the heap.

Comment: *"It should be better than incorrect code."* If you have your compiler's warnings set right, you shouldn't have this problem. I would see it as quite a negative if the standard said compilers had to enforce this, and I had no choice over the matter.

Comment: Uninitialized variables aren't a problem, __using__ uninitialized variables is a problem. Correct code doesn't have the problem and shouldn't be forced to pay any performance hit.

Comment: Zero is to benign. Much better is a non-benign value such as `0xDF` for a char, `0xDFDF` for a short, `0xDFDFDFDFDF` for an int, and so on. It's amazing how bad those values are. DF of course is short for dumb fool, or something similar.

Comment: @Blastfurnace So, taking that to logical conclusion, uninitialized variables are ok as long as you don't use them? Um.. If you're not going to use them, pardon the simplicity of the followup question: Why *have* them?? A compiler generating init-code for unused variables would certainly be a waste, but no bigger a fools errand than having the unused variables in the first place. Btw, I completely agree with you. Correct code shouldn't have that problem, and, in fact, won't if all variables *used* are initialized, be it by some init-code generated by come wannabe-smart compiler or the engineer.

Comment: followup. but you're absolutely right, without the ability to specify "initialize this for be because I just don't feel like doing it" anything done by the compiler would be pure overhead and completely unneeded in the end.

Comment: @WhozCraig A variable can be initially uninitialised, and then initialised and used only in some code paths. Why waste time initialising it if you're not sure that its going to be used?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson As soon as you said the words "and used" it disqualifies the "unused" state mentioned earlier. As I said I completely agree with BF. I only conjecture it to be made clear that uninitialized, *unused* variables are their own special kind of foolery. The idea of forcing default initialization is as repugnant to me as it is to BF, and likely to you too.

Comment: To be clearer, uninitialized variables are only a problem if you __read__ them. Correct code doesn't have code paths that read uninitialized variables.

Comment: @Blastfurnace completely agree.

Answer (score 3):

This argument is incomplete, actually. Unitialized variables may have two reasons: efficiency and the lack of a suitable default.

*1) Efficiency*

It is, mostly, a left-over of the old days, when C compilers were simply C to assembly translators and performed no optimization whatsoever.

These days we have smart compilers and [Dead Store Elimination](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#dse) which in most cases will eliminate redundant stores. Demo:

```
int foo(int a) {
    int r = 0;
    r = a + 3;
    return r;
}
```

Is transformed into:

```
define i32 @foo(i32 %a) nounwind uwtable readnone {
  %1 = add nsw i32 %a, 3
  ret i32 %1
}
```

Still, there are cases where even the smarter compiler cannot eliminate the redundant store and this may have an impact. In the case of a large array that is later initialized piecemeal... the compiler may not realize that all values will end up being initialized and thus not remove the redundant writes:

```
int foo(int a) {
    int* r = new int[10]();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= a; ++i) {
        r[i] = i;
    }
    return r[a % 2];
}
```

Note in the following the call to `memset` (that I required by suffixing the `new` call with `()` which is value initialization). It was not eliminated even though the `0` are unneeded.

```
define i32 @_Z3fooi(i32 %a) uwtable {
  %1 = tail call noalias i8* @_Znam(i64 40)
  %2 = bitcast i8* %1 to i32*
  tail call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* %1, i8 0, i64 40, i32 4, i1 false)
  br label %3

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %3, %0
  %i.01 = phi i32 [ 0, %0 ], [ %6, %3 ]
  %4 = zext i32 %i.01 to i64
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds i32* %2, i64 %4
  store i32 %i.01, i32* %5, align 4, !tbaa !0
  %6 = add i32 %i.01, 1
  %7 = icmp ugt i32 %6, %a
  br i1 %7, label %8, label %3

; <label>:8                                       ; preds = %3
  %9 = srem i32 %a, 2
  %10 = sext i32 %9 to i64
  %11 = getelementptr inbounds i32* %2, i64 %10
  %12 = load i32* %11, align 4, !tbaa !0
  ret i32 %12
}
```

*2) Default ?*

The other issue is the lack of a suitable value. While a `float` could perfectly be initialized to `NaN`, what of integers ? There is no integer value that represents the absence of value, none at all! `0` is one candidate (among others), but one could argue it's one of the worst candidate: it's a very likely number, and thus likely has a specific meaning for the usecase at hand; are you sure that you are comfortable with this meaning being the default ?

*Food for thought*

Finally, there is one neat advantage of unitialized variables: they are detectable. The compiler may issue warnings (if it's smart enough), and *Valgrind* **will** raise errors. This make logical issues **detectable**, and only what is detected can be corrected.

Of course a sentinel value, such as `NaN`, would be as useful. Unfortunately... there is none for integers.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways in which initialisation might impact performance.

First, initialising a variable takes time. Granted, for a single variable it's probably negligible, but as others have suggested, it can add up with large numbers of variables, arrays, etc.

Second, who's to say that zero is a reasonable default? For every variable for which zero is a  useful default, there's probably another one for which it isn't. In that case, if you do initialise to zero you then incur further overhead re-initialising the variable to whatever value you actually want. You essentially pay the initialisation overhead twice, rather than once if the default initialisation does not occur. Note that this is true no matter what you choose as a default value, zero or otherwise.

Given the overhead exists, it's typically more efficient to not initialise and to let the compiler catch any references to uninitialised variables.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a variable references a place in memory which can be modified to hold data.  For an unitialized variable, all that the program needs to know is where this place is, and the compiler usually figures this out ahead of time, so no instructions are required.  But when you want it to be initialized (to say, 0), the program needs to use an extra instruction to do so.

One idea might be to zero out the entire heap while the program is starting, with memset, then initialize all of the static stuff, but this isn't needed for anything that is set dynamically before it's read.  This would also be a problem for stack-based functions which would need to zero out their stack frame every time a function is called.  In short, it's much more efficient to allow variables to default to undefined, particularly when the stack is frequently being overwritten with newly called functions.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with -Wmaybe-uninitialized and find out. Those are the only places the compiler would not be able to optmize out the primitive initialization.

As for the heap ...

Comment: It's one hell of an annoying warning though :(

Comment: True. I suggested turning on the warning because counting the warning messages generated by the code provides a decent estimate of the cost.